# What's wrong with my on blur/focus script?

Tags: jquery

I can't get this to work, what's wrong?

I want to set value, on blur and on focus on my inputs with the class "ginput_quantity"

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.ginput_quantity').val(0);

$(document).on('blur','.ginput_quantity',function(){
if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0';}
})

$(document).on('focus','.ginput_quantity',function(){
if (this.value == '0') {this.value = '';}
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="" class="ginput_quantity">
<input type="text" value="" class="ginput_quantity">
<input type="text" value="" class="ginput_quantity">
<input type="text" value="" class="ginput_quantity">
<input type="text" value="" class="ginput_quantity">
</body>
</html>
```

Link: http://webintas.dk/jstest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work perfectly except the first line `$('.ginput_quantity').val(0);` Because you are using `event-delegation` on the other blocks of code. So those part wont require to be inside of .ready() handler.

Or

If you want to achieve this concept without using any `JS` , you can go for `place holders`. Please have a look at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) to grab more knowledge about it.

Wrap your code inside the `.ready()` handler.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.ginput_quantity').val(0);

   $(document).on('blur','.ginput_quantity',function(){
    if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0';}
   })

   $(document).on('focus','.ginput_quantity',function(){
    if (this.value == '0') {this.value = '';}
   })

});
```

Comment: I know the placeholder - very smart, but not in my case.